# How to make (DBMS_LOCK package) exclusive lock with higher priority than share lock

Tags: oracle, locking

Let say the following locks are acquired by different processes in the time order specified below.

```
Process 1: Share lock, last for 100 seconds
10 seconds later
Process 2: Share lock, last for 1 seconds
20 seconds later
Process 3: Exclusive lock
1 second later
Process 4: Share lock, last for very long time
```

As shown above, Process 4 will get the share lock even Process 3 requests an exclusive lock earlier than Process 4 because Process 1 holds a share lock a bit long.

It is not the behavior I want. What I want is that Process 3 should get the exclusive lock earlier than Process 4. I want the exclusive lock take higher priority so that all share locks requested after the exclusive lock should be pended. Sure, share locks acquired by Process 1 and 2 should be released before exclusive lock (Process 3) can be acquired.

It looks like that there is no built-in mechanism in Oracle to achieve the behavior I want.

The only way I can think of is to have a custom synchronization mechanism in my application logic. One possible approach is to use additional synchronization objects or flags to coordinate the acquisition of shared and exclusive locks.

For example, I could use a database table to indicate the state of the lock. When it comes to Process 4 to acquire the share lock, the process will check the table and see if there is any exclusive lock is requested earlier. If yes, it will be pended a while until the exclusive lock is requested successfully.

Or is there any built-in (preferred)/better mechanism to achieve this?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.